# Replace Nested Object with Map

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace a nested object with an updated object with map. However, it only works if I replace each property but I cannot replace the entire object with the updated one. The following is my strucutre:

```
[
    {
        name: 'Parent 1',
        data: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'Child 1', 
                // more properties ...,
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Child 2', 
                // more properties ...
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Now I want to replace a child in its parent with an updated child. This is what I have right now and it works but it isn't maintainable to map each property manually:

```
    parents.map(parent =>
        parent.data.map(child => {
            if (child.id === newChild.id) {
                child.name = newChild.name;
                // more mappings ...
            }
        })
    );
```

This is what doesn't work but the solution I would prefer:

```
    parents.map(parent =>
        parent.data.map(child => {
            if (child.id === newChild.id) {
                child= newChild;
            }
        })
    );
```

I am also open to other solutions rather than using map. I am not sure if this is the correct way of doing it.

Comment: Post the result you are expecting... And i'm am almost sure map is not a way to go to "replace" anything in object...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where the `newChild` is coming from, but...

If you want to replace that whole child, you have to use its index. Like so,

```
parents.forEach(parent => parent.data.forEach((child, index) => {
    if (child.id == newChild.id) child.data[index] = newChild;
}));
```

If not , you are just changing the value of the variable `child` in that loop.

I changed the `map` to `forEach` since I assume you want to edit the original array. Use this

```
parents = parents.map(parent => parent.data.map((child, index) => (child.id == newChild.id) ? newChild : child));
```

This way, the new child will take this space of the old one in the map if their `ids` match else the old child will still be returned

Comment: Thanks! The first approach works with the forEach loop. The second approach is what I have also tried but it doesn't work. That is what I am confused about.

Comment: The `map` doesn't mutate the array. If you want to use `map`, you still have to assign a variable to it

Comment: I have tried your first approach and the second approach. The first approach works perfectly, the second doesn't. It still returns the old array and nothing is replaced.

Comment: Did you `log` out the return value or assign it to a variable?

Comment: Damn, I am so stupid! Thanks so much, what you described fixed my issue.

Comment: Glad you finally got it. :D... Good Luck with the rest of your code

Answer (score 0):

this is your original script, I just add the index of the data array to the map and changed the way to assign the value to child. At this case I assign the newChild to parent.data[index]. This is the code:

```
parents.map((parent) =>
    parent.data.map((child, itemChild) => {
        if (child.id === newChild.id) {
            parent.data[itemChild] = newChild;
        }
    })
);
```